# php str_replace частично меняет строку, вместо того, чтобы заменить ее полностью

Tags: php, строки, str-replace

У меня есть большой массив вида

```
$arr = [
    'Entry' => 'Запись',
    'Attachments' => 'Файлы',
    '2 weeks ago' => '2 недели назад',
    'A week ago' => 'Неделю назад',
    ...
];
```

В нем порядка 910 пар ключ значение

Также есть js файл в котором нужно поменять русские слова на английские

Например было `<div>'+Послезавтра+', </div>`, а нужно чтобы стало `<div>'+In 2 days+', </div>`

В итоге попробовал открывать файл в `file_get_contents` циклом идти по массиву и на каждой итерации с помощью `str_replace` менять строки.
Частично это отрабатывает верно, однако на некоторых строках срабатывает не корректно

Например

меняет `"Месяц"` не на `"Month"` а на `"Monthяц"` или

меняет `"Жизнь"` не на `"Life"` а на `"Жofнь"`

Также на некоторых строках он добавляет запятые Например `"Вторник"` меняет на `"Tueорн,к"` вместо `"Tuesday"`

При этом при запуске одиночных замен (без прохода по массиву) Все меняется корректно, что на мой взгляд исключает проблему кодировок и пр.

Мое предположение, что сбоит из-за огромного файла (> 75k строк - не спрашивайте, это действительно грустно), но как подтвердить эту гипотезу и самое главное, как это исправить, я не знаю.

Comment: Здравствуйте, c такой задачей не сталкивался. Но, посмотрел бы в сторону памяти. Попробуйте увеличить память: php ini memory limit

Comment: Дайте знать если решите задачу, мне самому интересно из за чего такое происходит.

Comment: Попробуйте вот эту функцию https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882291/11777454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `str_replace` используйте `mb_str_replace`. И вообще для русских строк используйте функции с префиксом "mb_"

Про многобайтовые строки можно почитать в доках

- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.mbstring.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.mbstring.php

Comment: у него там основная проблема с подстроками. Если сначала в файле было `week => "неделя"`, то в итоге будет не `2 weeks ago`, а `2 неделяs ago`